# Print using command line arguments

Tags: c, linux, environment-variables

Im trying make a program print a specific output using a enviroment variable in the command line, but the program seems to be stuck on my first input.

Here's my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>



void print_data(char*select);

int main (int argc, char * argv[]){

int ret;
char *ch = NULL;


   if( argc == 2)
   {
      ch = argv[1];
   }
   else
   {
      ch = getenv("V1");
   }

   void print_data(ch);

   return 0;
}
void print_data(char* select){

      if(select, "k")
      {
          printf("Value set to key\n");
      }
      else if(select, "l")
      {
         printf("Value set to last name\n");
      }
      else if (select, " ")
      {
         printf("Value set to %s\n", select);
      }
   }
```

My problem is that the program either only prints "Value set to key" or "Value set to last name".
How can I use the pointer in Print_data to check what command is entered in the command line?

Output: [image]

Comment: What are you trying to do with `if(select, "k")`?

Comment: Trying to check if the argument I put in main(command line) is k, using a pointer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if(select, "k")` is almost certainly not doing what you want, but it is not entirely clear what it is that you want.  That expression is equivalent to `if(1)`, which is why you get the behavior you see.  Perhaps you intend:

```
if( select[0] == 'k' ) ...
else if( select[0] == 'l' ) ...
else if( select[0] == ' ' ) ...
```

which would be better written:

```
switch( select[0] ) {
case 'k': ...;
...
```

Comment: There is also a problem with `void print_data(ch);` inside `main`

Comment: Thanks, that helped. But would "select" be the default invironment variable when I dont have any input?

Comment: What's the problem in main?

Comment: @B0ris If argc != 2, then select will be the result of `getenv`, which may be NULL, in which case `select[0]` will (almost certainly) lead to a segmentation fault.

Comment: @B0ris `void print_data(ch);` should be `print_data(ch);` or `(void)print_data(ch);` (not necessary since `print_data` already return `void`, but legal)

Comment: Ok, so I could change the "else" to else if(argc < 2 ) and else(argc == 1) ?

Comment: @B0ris You need to deal with `getenv` returning NULL.